# dplyr: whats the difference between group_by and group_by_ functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't figure out what the underscore-based function is for the group_by_() function.

From the group_by help:

```
by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)  
summarise(by_cyl, mean(disp), mean(hp))
```

yields the expected:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]  
    cyl mean(disp)  mean(hp)
1   4   105.1364  82.63636
2   6   183.3143 122.28571
3   8   353.1000 209.21429
```

but this:

```
by_cyl <- group_by_(mtcars, cyl)
```

yields an error:

```
"Error in as.lazy_dots(list(...)) : object 'cyl' not found"
```

So my question is what does the underscore version do? And also, under what circumstances would I want to use it, rather than the "regular" one?

Thanks

Comment: You could define `cyl` in another variable and pass it with `group_by_`.  `someVar <- 'cyl';
 by_cyl <- group_by_(mtcars, someVar)`

Comment: Reading the [Non-standard evaluation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) `dplyr` package vignette would be a good place to start.

Comment: `by_cyl <- group_by_(mtcars, "cyl")` will work (as commented by @akrun)

Comment: @akrun.  I think I understand now.  To rephrase your answer: rather than having the `group_by()` variable hard-coded, it can be calculated on-the-fly, thereby allowing the programmer to use any of the data.frame's columns at runtime, if desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The dplyr Non-Standard Evaluation vignette helps here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

**Note**: the above link is now out of date, but the same information can be found on the github page for the package.
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/34423af89703b0772d59edcd0f3485295b629ab0/vignettes/nse.Rmd

> Dplyr uses non-standard evaluation (NSE) in all of the most important
> single table verbs: filter(), mutate(), summarise(), arrange(),
> select() and group_by(). NSE is important not only to save you typing,
> but for database backends, is what makes it possible to translate your
> R code to SQL. However, while NSE is great for interactive use it’s
> hard to program with. This vignette describes how you can opt out of
> NSE in dplyr, and instead rely only on SE (along with a little
> quoting).
>
> ...
>
> Every function in dplyr that uses NSE also has a version that uses SE.
> There’s a consistent naming scheme: the SE is the NSE name with _ on
> the end. For example, the SE version of summarise() is summarise_(),
> the SE version of arrange() is arrange_(). These functions work very
> similarly to their NSE cousins, but the inputs must be “quoted”

Comment: that link is broken

Comment: As a python user, reading all these answers for coding in R confuses me quite a lot. Why do R programmers on StackOverflow 
1. Not explain with clear examples (which is seen a lot in python answers). 
2. Give links to documentation instead of explaining code in simple terms. 

I've seen this quite a lot. Can anyone correct me on why I see this trend?
I do see some R users trying to follow good methods, but they cover only 1-2% of the major Questions and answers that I have come across on StackOverflow.
thanks.