# Why do group_by and group_by_ give different answers when summarizing by two variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the following example, I want to create a summary statistic by two variables.  When I do it with `dplyr::group_by`, I get the correct answer, by when I do it with `dplyr::group_by_`, it summarizes one level more than I want it to.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(919)
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  b = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  x = runif(6)
)

# Gives correct answer
df %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(x))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: a [?]
# 
#       a     b     total
#   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1     3 1.5214746
# 2     1     4 0.7150204
# 3     2     4 0.1234555
# 4     2     5 0.8208454

# Wrong answer -- too many levels summarized
df %>%
  group_by_(c("a", "b")) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(x))
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#       a     total
#   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1 2.2364950
# 2     2 0.9443009
```

What's going on?

Comment: Might help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667059/dplyr-whats-the-difference-between-group-by-and-group-by-functions

Comment: Thanks @wbrugato.  I did see that.  It explains how the inputs to the functions are different (quoted vs. unquoted strings), but it doesn't explain why the functions would give different outputs from the same inputs (but please let me know if I'm missing something!).

Comment: You need `group_by_(.dots = c("a", "b"))` or `group_by_("a", "b")`.

Comment: @Psidom that did the trick, thanks!  If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a vector of variable names, you can pass it to `.dots` parameter as:

```
df %>%
      group_by_(.dots = c("a", "b")) %>%
      summarize(total = sum(x))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: a [?]

#      a     b     total
#  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1     3 1.5214746
#2     1     4 0.7150204
#3     2     4 0.1234555
#4     2     5 0.8208454
```

Or you can use it in the same way as you would do in NSE way:

```
df %>%
     group_by_("a", "b") %>%
     summarize(total = sum(x))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: a [?]

#      a     b     total
#  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1     3 1.5214746
#2     1     4 0.7150204
#3     2     4 0.1234555
#4     2     5 0.8208454
```