# Call input in shiny for a group by function

Tags: r, input, group-by, shiny

I am trying to make an app with shiny. The principle should to be simple: Show one table for every input.
Here is my code. The app show the sum for enitre database, but I don't want that.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Casco Monthly"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2(strong("Shiny App"),style = "color:blue"),
      img(src = "groupama.jpg", height = 100, width = 200),
      selectInput("select", h3("Categorii"), 
                  choices = list("CLIENT_TYPE" = "CLIENT_TYPE", "Grupare.Leasing" = "Grupare.Leasing",
                                 "AGENT_TYPE" = "AGENT_TYPE", "Grupare.vehicul" = "Grupare.vehicul",
                                  "Grupare.vechime"="Grupare.vechime"),
                  selected = "CLIENT_TYPE"),
      selectInput("select2",label = "Client Type",
                  choices = c ("NONE","Categorie_client"),
                  selected = "NONE")),

    mainPanel(
      h1(strong("CASCO 3003")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("table1")))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {


  aggregated <- reactive({
    DATA %>%
      group_by("3003"=input$select) %>%
      summarise("Earned Premium" = sum(EP), "Exposure" = sum(EXP),"GWP" = sum(GWP_RON), "Incurred" = sum(INC),"NO of events" = sum(Nr.evenim))
  })

  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    aggregated()

})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For example:

```
CLIENT_TYPE EP  EXP GWP INC NR.EVENIM
PF      10  1   1000    30  2
PF      20  4   2000    50  1
PF      50  5   1500    60  2
PJ      20  3   2500    20  1
PJ      40  7   2000    10  1
PJ      30  8   500     20  2
PJ      20  9   1500    20  1
```

I wanted to obtain smth like that:

```
CLIENT_TYPE Earnend Premium Exposure    GWP    Incurred  No of events
PF                 80          10       4500      140           5
PJ                110          27       6500       70           5
```

But, in fact the app shows grand total:

```
3003          Earnend Premium   Exposure    GWP     Incurred     No of events
CLIENT_TYPE        190             37      11000      210            10
```

I hope smbd understand what I am trying to say.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you used `input$select`, it is a string (`input$select = "CLIENT_TYPE"`).

So you need to use the function `group_by_()` (or `group_by_at()`) instead of the function `group_by()`. This function will understand that the string should be consider as a variable of the data.frame.

More information here: [dplyr: whats the difference between group_by and group_by_ functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667059/dplyr-whats-the-difference-between-group-by-and-group-by-functions)

```
aggregated <- reactive({
  DATA %>%
    group_by_(input$select) %>%
    summarise(  [...] )
})
```

or

```
aggregated <- reactive({
  DATA %>%
    group_by_at(input$select) %>%
    summarise(  [...] )
})
```

Comment: OMG, it works. Thank you, I tried at least 1 week. Thank you very much!!

Comment: it is recommended to use `group_by_at()` now

Comment: @demarsylvain   Please update your answer:  group_by(across(input$select)) %>%