# How to convert a string to a variable and to loop through group_by?

Tags: r, string, loops, variables, contingency

Assume I have a dataset with two columns, Location and Product, that shows how many of each product is sold at each location. I create a contingency table for the number of each product sold at each location:

```
data%>% 
  group_by(Location,Product)%>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = product, values_from = n)
```

Now, imagine that instead of a single Product column, I have US_Product, Japan_Product,..., Germany_Product. How can I create my contingency tables in a for loop? 
NOTE: when I create a vector of products like `p<-c("Product1", "Product2",..., "Product3")` and loop through these products, I get an error message because these are strings and not variable names.

Here is a minimal example:

```
Location <- c("AB","ON","MN","AB","ON")
Product1<-c("Type1","Type2","Type1","Type3","Type1")
Product2<-c("Type3","Type2","Type3","Type3","Type2")
Product3<-c("Type1","Type2","Type1","Type1","Type1")
data <- tibble(Location,Product1,Product2,Product3)
data%>% 
  group_by(Location,Product1)%>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Product1, values_from = n) #this works as expected

#now I want to do the same thing in a loop
prodV <- c("Product1","Product2","Product3")
for (i in c(1:3)){
  var <- prodV[i]
  data%>% 
    group_by(Location,var)%>%
    summarize(n=n()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = n)   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

If we need to use it in a loop, then one option is `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
map(p, ~ 
         data%>% 
           group_by_at(vars("Location", .x)) %>%
           summarize(n=n()) %>%
           pivot_wider(names_from = .x, values_from = n))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
p <- c("cyl", "vs", "am")
map(p, ~ 
         mtcars %>% 
             group_by_at(vars('gear', .x)) %>% 
             summarise(n = n()) %>%
             pivot_wider(names_from = .x, values_from = n) )
```

---

Or if we use a `for` loop, then create an empty `list` to store the output from each iteration ('out'), loop over the 'p' values, and change only the `.x` part from `map` while assigning the output to each element of 'out' `list`

```
out <- vector('list', length(p))
names(out) <- p
for(p1 in p) {
       out[[p1]] <- data %>%
                      group_by_at(vars("Location", p1)) %>%
                      summarize(n = n()) %>%
                      pivot_wider(names_from = p1, values_from = n)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is the thing you are after. Below is a base R solution to make  contingency tables:

```
p <- c("US_Product","Japan_product","Germany_Product")
res <- Map(function(x) table(df[c("Location",x)]),p)
```

such that

```
> res
$US_Product
        US_Product
Location a b c
      XX 2 0 1
      YY 1 1 2

$Japan_product
        Japan_product
Location d e f
      XX 0 2 1
      YY 3 0 1

$Germany_Product
        Germany_Product
Location g i j
      XX 0 3 0
      YY 1 1 2
```

**Dummy DATA**

```
df <- > dput(df)
structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("XX", "YY"), class = "factor"), US_Product = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    Japan_product = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("d", 
    "e", "f"), class = "factor"), Germany_Product = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("g", "i", "j"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle the problem using `group_by_at` as opposed to `group_by`. According to [dplyr: whats the difference between group_by and group_by_ functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667059/dplyr-whats-the-difference-between-group-by-and-group-by-functions)
if one needs to have inputs with quotation marks, SE versions of functions should be used, instead of NSE versions---please see the link for a detailed explanation.

```
prodV <- c("Product1","Product2","Product3")
for (i in c(1:3)){
  var <- prodV[i]
  a<-data%>% 
    group_by_at(vars("Location",var))%>%
    summarize(n=n()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = n)   
  print(a)
}
```